# Can you link a static library to a DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let's say I have an app called `foo`, a library called `lib` and my own DLL called `col`.

`foo` is coded to take some of its code and resources from the `col` DLL. But would it work if I were to statically link `lib` to `col` and `foo` would find it? Is it possible?

*Note: I'm talking about Visual C++, not GCC*

Comment: No.  DLLs must export their functions.  Only those exported functions are visible to be referenced externally (dynamic linkage must occur).  You could create a wrapper, and export the wrapper.  Another possibility is to create a 2nd DLL that is the wrapper, and then have foo and col both link against THAT DLL.

Comment: You'll need a [.def file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=msvc-170) or embed linker /export commands with [#pragma comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170).